# The @PostConstruct method in JSF is invoked on every AJAX call even though the managed bean is given a view scope

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces, jsf-2.2, postconstruct

Given the following simple test case.

```
<h:form id="form" prependId="true">
    <p:commandButton value="Submit" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.action}"/>
    <p:commandLink value="Submit" actionListener="#{testManagedBean.action}"/>
</h:form>
```

The JSF managed bean involved :

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public final class TestManagedBean implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println("init() called");
        // May invoke expensive business services like EJB calls.
    }

    public void action() {
        System.out.println("action() called.");
    }
}
```

When either `<p:commandButton>` or `<p:commandLink>` given is pressed, the `init()` method is invoked in addition to the the action listener - `action()`.

This should not happen, since the `init()` method may have expensive business services which should not be invoked unnecessarily on every AJAX request.

Is there a way to prevent this behaviour? The `init()` method should not be invoked on AJAX calls.

I'm using JSF 2.2.6 and PrimeFaces 5.0 final.

Comment: Not happening to me in Tomcat 7 + Mojarra 2.2.6. Could you provide more info about your environment?

Comment: Would probably be interresting to see `faces-config.xml`

Comment: This is likely my first question where I cannot give any feedback. The problem was being caused somewhere else that made me think it was cased by the `@PostConstruct` method. It was fixed but I just cannot describe and in fact, it is unrelated to the example as shown in the question.

Comment: Does your import statements consists "javax.faces.view.ViewScoped" instead of "javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped". I made this mistake and took a day to find this silly mistake :)

Comment: No it is `javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped`. @SrikanthGanji

Answer (score -1):

Use `import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;` if the managed bean is not a CDI artifact.